# Write Java method which merge two 2D Arrays into 1 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am looking for a method which will merge two 2D arrays into one 2D array.

Arrays may store any types of data.

For example I have:

```
Object[][] dataProvider = new Object[][]{
                {12, 6.0}, {6, 3.0}
        };

Object[][] impl = new Object[][]{
                {1}, {2}, {3}
        };
```

As a result should be array below:

```
Object[][] result = new Object[][]{

{1, 12, 6.0}
{1, 6, 3.0}
{2, 12, 6.0}
{2, 6, 3.0}
{3, 12, 6.0}
{3, 6, 3.0}

 };
```

here is my code:

```
public Object[][] merge(Object[][] impl, Object[][] dataProvider) {
        int n = dataProvider.length;
        int m = impl.length;

        Object[][] merged = new Object[m * n][];
        int countLines = 0;

        for (Object[] objects : impl) {
            for (Object[] value : dataProvider) {
                int g = objects.length + value.length;
                List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int j = 0; j < objects.length; j++) {
                    list.add(j, impl[j]);
                }

                for (int k = 0; k < value.length; k++) {
                    list.add(list.size(), value);
                }

                merged[countLines] = list.toArray();
                countLines++;
                list.clear();
            }
        }
        return merged;
    }
```

The output for merge[0] is [1], [12, 6.0], [12, 6.0]
The output should be [1, 12, 6.0]

Could you please help me to find a mistake in the method?
Thanks ahead!

Comment: What evidence do you have that there is a mistake?

Comment: In other words, what's wrong with your current code? Are you getting the wrong output (if yes, what)? An exception (if yes, what and where)? Something else?

Comment: when I try to print merged[0][1] element I got [12, 6.0] instead of [12]

Comment: @MyroslavaVynokur please [edit] your question to include that piece of information. It's an integral part of your question, so it belongs there, not in comments.

Comment: By the way, how are you printing it? Printing a specific index of a 2-dimensinal array shouldn't print an array.

Comment: `list.add(j, impl[j]);` should be `list.add(objects[j]);`. Also `list.add(list.size(), value);` should be `list.add(value[k]);` Please note that `impl` is 2d array so `impl[j]` holds single *row* (1d array) from it but you want data *from* that row. Same about `value` which is actually *row* inside `dataProvider`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I try to print it by element:
System.out.println(Arrays.toString((Object[]) merged[0][0]));

Comment: By the way, this type of merge is known as Cartesian Product.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca your correction helped me :) many thanks!

Comment: BTW you can replace content of your inner loop with this one line `merged[countLines++] = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(objects), Arrays.stream(value)).toArray();`.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks a lot! will also try it

Comment: If streams are not clear for you yet, you can also easily add all elements from array to list via [`Collections.addAll(list, array);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,%20T...)) which can replace each of your index based `for` loop. BTW your `int g` is never used so you can remove it.

Comment: @Pshemo yes, I noticed it at the end because of IntelliJ suggestion. But solution with streams is also great (hope will learn more about streams soon), thanks

Comment: @James thanks a lot for a tip, I am about to explore it

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of loops and stream this will merge the two as requested.

```
Object[][] dataProvider =
        new Object[][] { { 12, 6.0 }, { 6, 3.0 } };
Object[][] impl = new Object[][] { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 } };

Object[][] result = merge(impl, dataProvider);

for (Object[] arr : result) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

prints

```
[1, 12, 6.0]
[1, 6, 3.0]
[2, 12, 6.0]
[2, 6, 3.0]
[3, 12, 6.0]
[3, 6, 3.0]
```

This will allow the first and second arrays to be merges as described above.  Any type is supported.

- compute the length of the resultant array
- Allocate a result array
- stream the two arrays and assign to the appropriate array.
- return the result.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[][] merge(T[][] first, T[][] second) {
    int rows = first.length * second.length;
    T[][] result = (T[][]) new Object[rows][];
    int r = 0;
    for (T[] arr : first) {
        for (T[] arr2 : second) {
            result[r++] = (T[]) Stream.of(arr, arr2)
                    .flatMap(Arrays::stream).toArray();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: many thanks for the answer! I will try to simplify my code according to your suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just concat the rows of your arrays using copy methods:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object[][] impl = {{1}, {2}, {3}};

        Object[][] dataProvider = {{12, 6.0}, {6, 3.0}};

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(merge(impl, dataProvider)));
    }

    public static Object[][] merge(Object[][] impl, Object[][] dataProvider) {
        int n = dataProvider.length;
        int m = impl.length;

        Object[][] merged = new Object[m * n][];
        int row = 0;

        for (Object[] objects : impl) {
            for (Object[] value : dataProvider) {
                merged[row++] = concatArrays(objects, value);
            }
        }

        return merged;
    }

    static Object[] concatArrays(Object[] array1, Object[] array2) {
        Object[] result = Arrays.copyOf(array1, array1.length + array2.length);
        System.arraycopy(array2, 0, result, array1.length, array2.length);
        return result;
    }
}
```

output:

```
[[1, 12, 6.0], [1, 6, 3.0], [2, 12, 6.0], [2, 6, 3.0], [3, 12, 6.0], [3, 6, 3.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The main mistake is that your method's code is very difficult.

Let me introduce you to my solution

```java
    Object[][] merge(Object[][] array1, Object[][] array2) {
        Object[][] result = new Object[array1.length * array2.length][];
        for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; ++j) {
                result[i * array2.length + j] = merge(array1[i], array2[j]);
            }
        return result;
    }

    Object[] merge(Object[] array1, Object[] array2) {
        return Stream.of(array1, array2)
                .flatMap(Stream::of)
                .toArray(Object[]::new);
    }
```

merge(impl, dataProvider) gives exactly what you want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: many thanks! it really looks much simpler, thanks again!